# iOS keep user on Keychain sometimes does not work

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

On `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)` I check if user has logged in before as the following:

```
let user = KeychainManager().getCurrentUser()
if user.isValid() {
    self.redirectToMain()
}
else {
    self.redirectToWelcome()
}
```

This is how `getCurrentUser()` method looks like:

```
let currentUser = CurrentUser()
currentUser.Id = Int(KeychainWrapper.stringForKey(KeychainKeyConstants.idKeyForKeychain).toNonNullable("0"))
currentUser.email = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey(KeychainKeyConstants.emailKeyForKeychain).toNonNullable("")
// Other properties...
return currentUser
```

This is how I save user into Keyhchain:

```
let currentUser = CurrentUser()
currentUser.Id = loginModel.Id
currentUser.email = loginModel.email
// Some other properties...
KeychainManager().saveCurrentUser(currentUser)
```

This is how `saveCurrentUser()` method looks like:

```
KeychainWrapper.setObject(user.Id!, forKey: KeychainKeyConstants.idKeyForKeychain)
KeychainWrapper.setString(user.email, forKey: KeychainKeyConstants.emailKeyForKeychain)
// More properties...
```

Here is `isValid()` method of `CurrentUser`:

```
if self.Id == nil || self.email.isEmpty /* other properties... */ { return false }
return true
```

This logic mostly works but under some circumstances it does not. I, sometimes, surprisingly being redirected to the login page (`redirectToWelcome()`) even if I am already logged in. Once I encountered that problem while I was debugging the app, the problem was there were some values were not fetched (I didn't have a chance to see which values). I can't reproduce the error, I can't see what causes that problem.

I use `KeychainWrapper` to access Keychain, here: `https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper`

Has anybody got any idea for that? What could possibly may cause that issue?

Comment: did you get any errors back? there are some known issues with the keychain...

Comment: I hope I got some error, no, there's no any error back. I am just redirected to the login page.

Comment: @Wain What kind of issues are you referring to, API gotchas, or actual bugs?

Comment: bugs, keychain is inaccessible sometimes for unknown reasons

Comment: @Wain can you show me the source of this bug?

Comment: example discussion: https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain/issues/52